# MySQL syntax for order by not accepted in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I'm working through the SQL snippets for nested sets in [this article by Mike Hillyer](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The article is using MySQL, but I'm using SQL Server.  I get the following error reported when attempting to execute the query that should return the immediate subordinates of a node.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

What do I need to change to get this query to work on MSSQL?

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth <= 1
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Comment: Why does your subquery need an order by? Did you try just removing it? I don't understand what possible point it serves, even if you do add the `TOP` hack. Of course, what do you expect to happen when you have more than one row for any given node?

Comment: The query seems very inefficient. There are probably much better ways to write it, in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for your comment, I will try and remove the order by.  I can't exactly say I understand the query (yet) I just copied it from the website I referenced.  The website references the Joe Celko book on trees and hierarchies which seems to be the "go-to" book for this subject.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @ypercubeᵀᴹ.  Care to have a go at re-writing it? :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - In the past, MySQL would use the subquery's `ORDER BY` to feed items to the outer query in a particular order.  That made "groupwise max" work quite easily and efficiently.  But the standard says there is no order in a subquery, so now MySQL (and, I assume MSSQL) ignores the `ORDER BY`.  The "rgt-lft" algorithm dates back more than a decade in MySQL docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [sub_tree] derived table is using an `ORDER BY` with no `TOP` operator.

Try something like the following:

```
    SELECT TOP (1) node.name
    [...]
    ORDER BY node.lft
) AS sub_tree
```

Granted that you are just following a MySQL book, I should probably mention the whole "no-no" on doing old style joins on SQL Server. Use `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc rather than `FROM a,b,c WHERE a.id =b.id`.